# rspec core Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

Hello i'm testing my application with rspec:

this is the test file.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe RecipesController do
    render_views
    describe "index" do
        before do
            Recipe.create!(name: "Spaghetti alla Carbonara")
            Recipe.create!(name: "Spaghetti alle vongole e cozze")
            Recipe.create!(name: "Bistecca")
            Recipe.create!(name: "Fritto")

            xhr :get, :index, format: :json, keywords: keywords
        end

        subject(:results) { JSON.parse(response.body) }

        def extract_name 
            ->(object){ object["name"] } 
        end

        context 'quando la ricerca riporta dei risultati' do
            let(:keywords) { 'Spaghetti' }
            it 'essere 200' do
                expect(response.status).to eq(200)
            end

            it 'deve ritornare due risultati' do
                expect(results.size).to eq(2)
            end

            it 'deve esserci la ricetta Spaghetti alla Carbonara' do
                expect(results.map(&extract_name)).to include('Spaghetti alla Carbonara')
            end

            it 'deve esserci la ricetta Spaghetti alle vongole e cozze ' do
                expect(results.map(&extract_name)).to include('Spaghetti alle vongole e cozze')
            end
        end

        context 'quando la ricerca non riporta alcun risulato' do
            let(:keywords) { 'tortellini' }
            it 'non deve ritornare alcun risulato' do
                expect(results.size).to eq(0)
            end
        end


    end
end
```

when i try to launch the test via command:

> rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test ; rspec spec/controllers/recipes_controller_spec.rb

i recive this error

> /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.10.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup': You have already activated rspec-core 3.3.1, but your Gemfile requires rspec-core 2.99.2. Prepending`bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)

as described in the log the error is some conflict with the rspec-core v3.3.1 so in my gem file i've added this line for install the rspec-core v2.99.2

```
gem 'rspec-core', '~> 2.99.2'
```

but if i launch the command again (after the bundle install and with the bundle exec) the result is the same. someone have a similar problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try?

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/recipes_controller_spec.rb
```